# set fixed dimension of a div without depend to the devices where it is showed

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

in my page using jquery mobile I have a `div` and I would fixed the width without it depends to the devices where it is showed.for example in my iphone the div is showed correctly because the screen is small while in my ipad the div takes all the screen and it is really bad...how can I fixed its position?

Comment: what've you tried. .??. .post some code where your facing problems..!!

Comment: Well I didn't try anything...I have a div which became bigger or smaller in according where it is showed. I would fixed his width independently of device

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to code a site to look good on various devices. Check this out. http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/effective-design-multiple-screen-sizes

Comment: does it exist a method to avoid the div change dimension if I resize my browser windows? I would that block maintain its size

Comment: Basically you need to effectively add CSS to your site. Do you have some additional code to show us? That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`<div style='width: 100px'></div>`

Answer (score 0):

This is just general but you want to look at CSS 3 media queries to customize your layout specific to a device.